# Generating grid that matches Google Earth Engine polygons

Tags: coordinate-system, r, google-earth-engine, sf, africa

I'm trying to create a grid in `R` over the whole continent of Africa (I received some help in [this GIS StackExchange post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/396667/adequate-crs-when-creating-a-grid-over-a-whole-continent-in-r)), but I'm having trouble generating a grid that matches the `CRS` used in the Google Earth Engine, which I'm going to use later to download satellite imagery.

The discrepancies are higher when I depart from the Equator line. For instance, here is some code to generate a grid of 10 km by 10 km patches over South Africa, using the `stars` library:

```
library(sf)
library(stars)
library(giscoR)
library(tidyverse)

# country shapefile
south_africa <- gisco_get_countries(country="ZAF", resolution = 10)  %>% st_transform(3857)

# method 1: stars
grid = st_as_stars(st_bbox(south_africa), dx = 10000, dy = 10000)
grid = st_as_sf(grid)
grid = grid[south_africa, ]
```

Here I used `CRS 3857`, so I have my units in meters to define the grid. I can compute the area of the pixels, and get the geometry of a pixel so we can see that the area is correct (1, because I normalized it) under this coordinate reference system:

```
grid$area = st_area(grid$geometry)/(10000)^2
print(paste('area:',grid[[3]][[10000]]))
grid[[2]][[10000]]
```

```
[1] "area: 1"
POLYGON ((2331832 -3517624, 2341832 -3517624, 2341832 -3527624, 2331832 -3527624, 2331832 -3517624))
```

I also checked the grid using `st_make_grid`, and I obtain exactly the same results when checking the same patch in the grid:

```
grid_2=st_make_grid(south_africa, cellsize = 10000)
grid_2 = st_as_sf(grid_2)
grid_2 = grid[south_africa, ]
grid_2$area = st_area(grid_2$geometry)/(10000)^2  
print(paste('area:',grid_2[[3]][[10000]]))
grid_2[[2]][[10000]]
```

```
[1] "area: 1"
POLYGON ((2331832 -3517624, 2341832 -3517624, 2341832 -3527624, 2331832 -3527624, 2331832 -3517624))
```

The problem is that if I take this `polygon` and import it to Google Earth Engine, I see that the dimensions of the polygon are not right. In this case, I get that the square root of the area is `8,637` meters, and the average of the length of the sides of the polygon is `8,632` meters, but both measures should be `10,000` meters if the geometries where properly defined.

I also take a Landsat-8 Satellite image around the centroid of the polygon, covering 10km by 10km, and I obtain an image that is bigger than my polygon. Here you can see the satellite image, and the polygon in black:

[image: Satellite image around South Africa]

[Here is the code to visualize this in the code editor of Google Earth Engine](https://code.earthengine.google.com/b85bd0aee74e9bf9f1a3e5dd7430bb9b).

Is there any way in which I could fix this? I probably need to define a `CRS` that matches the one in Google Earth Engine. I tried working with `CRS  4326`, but I couldn't define a grid in meters with that CRS.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, it looks like you're preparing to export a lot of small chunks of imagery. I wonder if there are ways to do more processing in EE and then export larger chunks. What it is you are trying to accomplish in the end? Maybe I can suggest ways you might do more of the processing in EE. I don't mean to be presumptuous, just looking for opportunities to help :)

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks for the suggestion. I will generate a lot of satellite imagery in `GEE` to then use it to train a Convolutional Neural Network. I will also do more stuff in `R` with the grid, like computing some distances and intersecting the grid with other rasters, so I don't think I can do much more in `GEE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you are calculating areas and lengths, the projection is important to consider. Most `ee.Geometry` methods have parameters for `projection` and `maxError`; set them to specify what projection and tolerance to use for calculations.

In your script, I've added these arguments to the geometry methods and it computes the correct area and perimeter for the defined polygon and the buffered centroid matches the polygon (when buffer distance is defined in the desired 'EPSG:3857' projection).

[Full Code Editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/fe2175cb274a41e682b1430bfa050f7c)

For example:

```js
var MAXERROR = 0.001;
var PROJ = 'EPSG:3857';

var stars= ee.Geometry.Polygon([
  2331832, -3517624, 2341832, -3517624, 2341832,
  -3527624, 2331832, -3527624, 2331832, -3517624], PROJ, false);

print('square root of area', stars.area(MAXERROR, PROJ).sqrt());
print('average side size', stars.perimeter(MAXERROR, PROJ).divide(4));
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I had no idea how to pass those projection and error margin parameters to my functions. I'm now sure that the grid has the intended size, and I can add these parameters to my function that exports satellite imagery.